# How do I draw a complete box around a cropped shapefile using geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, geom

I currently have a ggplot of multiple shapefiles that are cropped to be inside a certain bounding box. I want to draw a complete box around the entire region, but the portions of the plot that crop out a shapefile polygon (Mexico's southern edge & Canada's northern edge) won't include the box.

```
pl = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = state_union, aes(fill = data)) +
  geom_sf(data = counties_thisState, aes(fill = data), color = "gray") +
  geom_sf(data = state_union, fill = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = canada, fill = "lightgray") +
  geom_sf(data = mexico, fill = "lightgray") + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-126, -66), ylim = c(22, 53), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors,
                    labels = c("0", "> 0 - 5.9", "6.0 - 20.9",
                               "21.0 - 50.9", "51.0 - 99.9", "> 100",
                               "States without reporting")) +
  annotation_scale(location = "br", width_hint = 0.2) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "br", which_north = "true",
                         pad_x = unit(0.5, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.25, "in"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) +
  xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
  labs(title = "Title", 
  fill = "Fill") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA))
```

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSezX.png)

I thought that including the theme after all the geom_sf functions would have the box be drawn completely over the polygons but this isn't the case.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide some example data that will let us reproduce the image you see in "result of above code" or a simplified version of it? Without a minimal reproducible example it is somewhat difficulty to help.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to know for sure without a [reproducible working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but my best guess is that the issue arises from using `panel.background` rather than `panel.border`. The latter draws on the top layer, the former draws on the bottom layer.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Example data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
```

## Make plot - panel.border

Note that white dashes on the border.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(color = "#1b98e0",
                                    fill = NA,
                                    size = 1))
```

[image]

## Make plot - panel.border

Note that white dashes on the border are gone.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(color = "#1b98e0",
                                  fill = NA,
                                  size = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! The panel.border is what I needed. Thank you.